# Can I make classmethod work with __getitem__?

Tags: python

In the code below, can I somehow keep `__getitem__` method (which cannot be a classmethod) on `Permissions` class and at the same time turn `as_list` into a class method?

Technically `as_list` IS a class method now, but I still need to do `cls()[user_type]` in it instead of just `cls[user_type]`, because it makes use of `__getitem__` method. I would also prefer an API like `Permissions.as_list()` over `Permissions().as_list()`.

```
from enum import Enum

class Permission(Enum):
    CAN_DELETE = 'can_delete'
    CAN_EDIT = 'can_edit'

class UserType(Enum):
    ADMIN = 'admin'
    GUEST = 'guest'

PERMISSIONS = {
    UserType.ADMIN: [Permission.CAN_DELETE, Permission.CAN_EDIT],
}

class UnknownUserTypeError(Exception):
    pass

class Permissions:
    permissions = PERMISSIONS

    def __getitem__(self, user_type: UserType):
        try:
            return self.permissions[user_type]
        except KeyError:
            raise UnknownUserTypeError

    @classmethod
    def as_list(cls, user_type: UserType):
        return [p.value for p in cls()[user_type]]

perms = Permissions.as_list(UserType.GUEST) # should raise UnknownUserTypeError
print(perms)
```

Comment: You can create a metaclass for class "Permissions" which implements `__getitem__`.

Comment: You can create a metaclass, but why do that when it's simpler to not use classes? The class just looks like complicated `dict`.

Comment: @tehCheat - because OP wants to encapsulate operations in a class.

Comment: @tdelaney Yeah, I get that, it just seems valid to ask what the benefit of encapsulating the operations in a class is. Dictionaries already have `__getitem__()`, why reinvent it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem completely, but you shouldn't create a new instance of `cls`. Just `return [p.value for p in cls.permissions[user_type]]`. let me know if that gets the result you want.

Comment: @tdelaney: `cls.permissions[user_type]` will bypass `__getitem__` and raise `KeyError` directly.

Answer (score 0):

This seems simpler without the use of Enums and classes.

How about:

```
CAN_DELETE = 'can_delete'
CAN_EDIT = 'can_edit'

ADMIN = 'admin'
GUEST = 'guest'

PERMISSIONS = {
    ADMIN: [CAN_DELETE, CAN_EDIT]
}

# perms = None, which can be checked with "if not" if you want to raise a custom exception
perms = PERMISSIONS.get(GUEST)

# Raises KeyError, which can be caught if you want to raise a custom exception
perms = PERMISSIONS[GUEST]
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I would prefer to stick with enums, with type safety in mind. Then,  without encapsulating permissions in a class, the client code needs to know too much about permissions implementation (it needs to look at `.value` for example, so it needs to know permissions are implemented as enums).

Comment: You're welcome. I would respectfully disagree, though; on the grounds that your argument (as I understand it, apologies if I am oversimplifying or misrepresenting) is that the answer works in practice but not in theory. IMHO writing less code that is easier to test is a Good Thing. But again, I may be misunderstanding or oversimplifying. Seems like some tests of behavior might serve as a worthy arbiter :)